# A complement of Milnor's book on singularities with exercises/examples

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, singularity-theory

I'm currently reading "Singular Point of Complex Hypersurfaces"  by Milnor.

This is really a great book, but I did realize I didn't saw any concrete examples, computations etc ...
I was wondering if there were a reference with exercises/examples which I can work, in parallel of reading the Milnor's book.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've never read Milnor's book, but I think this [book by Dimca](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-4404-2) might have some overlap. Definitely it has exercises. Probably there is some Hodge-y stuff in there that I doubt Milnor touches.

Comment: Hi ! I did begin to read the book and it looks really interesting. I think this was that I was looking for. Maybe this is a bit too advanced for me for now but I'll try to read it !! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Hoot : Dear Hoot, thanks again for pointing me this book ! With a bit more background I was able to read it. I really like the style and this is very interesting. I still need to become a bit stronger for fully understand everything but this is a great reference, thanks again !!